# ES7 Migration :: From Transport Client to API client

Tags: elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, apiclient, elasticsearch-client

I know that there exists documentation for migrating ES7 clients from [TransportClient to HighLevelRestClient] and [HighLevelRestClient to API client]. But I want to check if it is possible to directly migrate from [TransportClient to APIClient]

1. Is this even possible ?
2. If Yes, is there any documentation ?